# Angular 6 Property decorator issue

Tags: javascript, angular, decorator

Hey I am trying to test a sample decorator code as below.
It looks straight forward, but when I run it, I got the following error
"can not read property "firstname" of undefined.
It seems like the "this" can not refer to current context.
Any idea?

```
class Customer { 
  @hashify 
  public firstname: string; 
  public lastname: string; 

  constructor(firstname : string, lastname : string) { 
    this.firstname = firstname; 
    this.lastname = lastname; 
  } 
}

function hashify(target: any, key: string) { 
  var _value = this[key]; 

  var getter = function () { 
        return '#' + _value; 
  }; 

  var setter = function (newValue) { 
    _value = newValue; 
  }; 

  if (delete this[key]) { 
    Object.defineProperty(target, key, { 
      get: getter, 
      set: setter, 
      enumerable: true, 
      configurable: true 
    }); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: @AjayOjha just want to tryout the property decorator in Angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only issue your code has, is that the `this` value is incorrect. By changing that value to be `target`, your code works perfectly fine.

```
class Customer { 
  @hashify 
  public firstname: string; 
  public lastname: string; 

  constructor(firstname : string, lastname : string) { 
    this.firstname = firstname; 
    this.lastname = lastname; 
  } 
}

function hashify(target: any, key: string) { 
  var _value = target[key]; 

  var getter = function () { 
        return '#' + _value; 
  }; 

  var setter = function (newValue) { 
    _value = newValue; 
  }; 

  if (delete target[key]) { 
    Object.defineProperty(target, key, { 
      get: getter, 
      set: setter, 
      enumerable: true, 
      configurable: true 
    }); 
  } 
}
```

In your example, this is because the parameter `target` in the `PropertyDecorator` interface is a reference to object in which the decorator is applied.

Comment: Thanks. the only other thing is that the getter and setting should say "this._value" ....